# Perl parallel HTTP requests - out of memory

Tags: multithreading, perl

First of all, I'm new to Perl.
I want to make multiple (e.g. 160) HTTP GET requests on a REST API in Perl. Executing them one after another takes much time, so I was thinking of running the requests in parallel. Therefore I used threads to execute more requests at the same time and limited the number of parallel requests to 10. 
This worked just fine for the first time I ran the program, the second time I ran 'out of memory' after the 40th request.

Here's the code: (@urls contains the 160 URLs for the requests)

```
while(@urls) {
  my @threads;
  for (my $j = 0; $j < 10 and @urls; $j++) {
    my $url = shift(@urls);
    push @threads, async { $ua->get($url) };
  }

  for my $thread (@threads) {
  my $response = $thread->join;
  print "$response\n"; 
 }
}
```

So my question is, why am I NOT running out of memory the first time but the second time (am I missing something crucial in my code)? And what can I do to prevent it?
Or is there a better way of executing parallel GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would get a OOM error on a second run when you don't get one on the first run; when you run a Perl script and the perl binary exits, it'll release all of it's memory back to the OS.  Nothing is kept between executions.  Is the exact same data being returned by the REST service each time?  Maybe there's more data the second time you run and it's pushing you over the edge.

One problem I notice is that you're launching 10 threads and running them to completion, then spawning 10 more threads.  A better solution may be a worker-thread model.  Spawn 10 threads (or however many you want) at the start of the program, put the URLs into a queue, and allow the threads to process the queue themselves.  Here's a quick example that may help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @thr = map {
    threads->create(sub {
        my @responses = ();
        while (defined (my $url = $q->dequeue())) {
            push @responses, $ua->get($url);
        }
        return @responses;
    });
} 1..10;

$q->enqueue($_) for @urls;
$q->enqueue(undef) for 1..10;

foreach (@thr) {
    my @responses_of_this_thread = $_->join();
    print for @responses_of_this_thread;
}
```

Note, I haven't tested this to make sure it works.  In this example, you create a new thread queue and spawn up 10 worker threads.  Each thread will block on the dequeue method until there is something to be read.  Next, you queue up all the URLs that you have, and an `undef` for each thread.  The `undef` will allow the threads to exit when there is no more work to perform.  At this point, the threads will go through and process the work, and you will gather the responses via the join at the end.

Comment: To answer your question, the REST service returns the exact same data each time.
I tried your code, I had to change one line:
`my @thr = map { threads->create( sub { my $url = $q->dequeue(); return unless defined $url; $ua->get($url)}) } 1..10;`
This only performs 10 requests or did I make a mistake again?
However, sometimes it completes all 10 requests, sometimes I get an OOM error.

Comment: @user1771548 Joel made a small mistake while coding that quickly. I updated the code and it now loops *inside* the threads, what should be solving this part of the problem. No ideas on the memory issues, though.

Comment: Thank you now it works for all requests. It even executed successfully for the first three times I tried it - then I got the OOM error again. I'm thinking that maybe the REST service doesn't like that many requests in a short time.. For testing purposes it will be a bit hard but I won't need the program to run every minute so I will just have to live with it. Anyway, thank you both for your help!

Comment: could you not add a sleep to prevent the requests going through so fast to prove/disprove what you think may be causing out of memory error?

Comment: @user1771548 Do you have access to the REST server?  Can you check any of the logs for errors?

Comment: @dannix I added a sleep(10) and got an out of memory error again.

Comment: @Joel No, I don't have access to the server.

Comment: @user1771548 What module are you using for `$ua`?  A quick search on LWP and thread safe comes up with a few threads mentioning potential problems.  Have you looked at using LWP::Parallel for this (if you're not already)?

Comment: @user1771548 Also, what version of Perl are you using (`perl -v`) and on what platform are you running this on?

Comment: @Joel I'm using LWP::UserAgent, haven't not looked at LWP::Parallel yet. The version is 5.16.1, platform is Windows7, 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need an asynchronous solution Perl, I first look at the [POE](http://search.cpan.org/~rcaputo/POE-1.354/lib/POE.pm) framework. In this particular case I used [POE HTTP Request module](http://search.cpan.org/~rcaputo/POE-Component-Client-HTTP-0.947/lib/POE/Component/Client/HTTP.pm) that will allow us to send multiple requests simultaneously and provide a callback mechanism where you can process your http responses.

Perl threads are scary and can crash your application, especially when you join or detach them. If responses do not take a long time to process, a single threaded POE solution would work beautifully.

Sometimes though, we have to a rely on threading because application gets blocked due to long running tasks. In those cases, I create a certain number of threads BEFORE initiating anything in the application. Then with Thread::Queue I pass the data from the main thread to these workers AND never join/detach them; always keep them around for stability purposes.
(Not an ideal solution for every case.)

POE supports threads now and each thread can run a POE::Kernel. The kernels can communicate with each other through TCP sockets (which POE provides nice unblocking interfaces).

Comment: Pulling in all the POE stuff might be overkill with such a simple problem. Also, there is the issue of learning all that extra API. Perl threads are quite elegant once you understand the gotchas.

Comment: Nowadays, IMO, [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent) is a better framework, far easier to use.